# How to submit user scripts for Processing Toolbox?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-2.6

QGIS 2.6 change-log says that now there is some kind of repository where users can submit their scripts to make them available for everyone. Unfortunately I was unable to find any details about how to do this.

Comment: Try https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Processing/tree/master/scripts

Comment: Awesome. Is this preliminary or the final place to host them? Might push a commit or two

Comment: maybe @underdark can confirm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mapperz already commented, you can send pull requests to https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Processing/tree/master/scripts in order to submit new user scripts.

As far as I know, there are no plans to change to a different hosting platform for now since Github provides all necessary infrastructure.