# Sharing custom toolbox processes with others

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing, community

I would like to share my custom processes with others. Is there an official platform like the plugin repository where I can upload them, so others can search for it and install it without hassles?

Do you know any best practice examples of how to do that?

Comment: What about creating your own Github repo, like https://github.com/ssrebelious/QGIS_processing_scripts, or adding a pull request to https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Processing/pulls ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121055/how-to-submit-user-scripts-for-processing-toolbox . There does not seem to be any progress since then.

Comment: BTW some people put their processing algs into QGIS plugins to make them sharable: http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processing_gpf/